# POST AJAX returning empty array, even console.log has value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My ajax postdata is returning empty array on my php side. but if i console.log there is value of my post data. WHy im still receiving empty array?

[image]

this is my ajax code

```
$(document).on("submit","#form_registrationalumni", function(e){
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
       console.log(postData);
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl+"/register/registeralumni/", 
        type: 'POST',
        data: postData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data == 1){
                showSuccess('Thank you for Registering Louisian! Your registration is subject to evaluation, you will be receiving an email once registration is approved by the administrator.');
                clearForm('#form_registrationalumni');
            }else{
                showError(data);    
            }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

on my backend im just trying to simply display the array but it return 0
my whole code works on may localhost. this error is showing in my web server.

can anyone help me fix this. thanks in advance

this is my backend, i tried also checking my network if it is posted

[image]

Comment: If its working locally then my first thought would be check network request on web server and check if url is hitting your php code.

Comment: its hitting the php code, coz i echoed out a text and an empty array

Comment: can you show the php side, if you echo out an array (your comment above), maybe thats whats being outputted in the dom, your code is expecting `echo 1;` have you tried that?

Comment: Then hard to say anything without checking PHP code.

Comment: this is my backend.php
public function registeralumni(){
             echo 'this is the backend php';
             var_dump($_POST);
}

Comment: Check @LawrenceCherone comment. That's what happening i guess.

Comment: ive edited my post i added the backend

Comment: Anything other than 1 as response in JS will goto `else` and PHP is sending back array not echo 1.

Comment: it showing the error because i purposely printing the array not 1. the array is empty thats the problem here. even i change it to success(data){ console.log(data) } it will just display an empty array

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @user2182349  core_version = "1.10.2",

Comment: i tried removing some of the input fields and it returned some values, what would be the problem if my form is longand has file upload it wont work?

Comment: @Raymond, do this in your php side `echo json_encode($_REQUEST);` only and don't add any echo before this, and your ajax response side console the `data` variable, let me know what are you getting on console..

Comment: @turivishal im getting this in my console {"url":"register\/registeralumni\/"}